# C# MongoDB can we use Collection instance as a singleton?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dependency-injection, singleton, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoContext class that is registered as a singleton in DI. It accepts IMongoDatabase instance in the constructor.

Now what is the correct way to get the collection instance?
[image]

1. Use Expression bodied property as on the line 7, basically calling GetCollection each time the collection is accessed.
2. Call GetCollection in the ctor as on the line 13, and assign it only once (since the class is singleton)
3. Call GetCollection directly in the method where it will be used, line 18

As I understand, 1 and 3 are basically the same. They will call GetCollection every time the Collection is being accessed.

So the question is more like should we call GetCollection once or on every access?

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

all ways will work the same, since effectively both `MongoCollection` and `MongoDatabase` just use a cluster (roughly equal to MongoClient) inside that makes all logic to communicate with servers.